# Splitting out one large table into multiple smaller in Cassandra?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

Coming from a MongoDB background, we tend to split out ingestion of data into multiple collections (which house the same type of data) based on week. This is purely down to performance of our indexes.

Thinking about modelling this same concept in Cassandra, is it worth doing the same thing and having multiple tables based on time-period? So perhaps weekly tables again.

Are there any performance gains?

I ask this as well due to my research into the Hadoop integration, I may only want to map / reduce over a certain weeks worth of data and not all of the data and from what I can tell this is the best way to isolate the data we want to map over.

Thanks in advance for any input on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessary.  However, it's important to note that you should not be using secondary indexes with Cassandra, you should be modeling your data to match the queries you're performing.

If you're frequently looking to perform operations on a weekly basis, you may want to bucket your data by week.  That is, each partition has 1 week of data.  (A partition can contain multiple rows)

You may find it beneficial to go through this intro to Cassandra video that was filmed a few months ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W45Ysb9b6oE

Answer (score 0):

As Cassandra internals work you already have that. Nodes in Cassandra hold a number of PKs (Partition Keys) and it's data. If you choose a weekly PK data you're sorted. Cassandra will put all data for that specific PK in one node.

When you query Cassandra knows what node holds data for that PK. It will query only that node and retrieve the data. So Cassandra does what you're asking out of the box.

Comment: Yeah, that's what we do! :) I just wondered if I wanted to take a set of partition keys and map/reduce over the rows 9columns) in them. Is it better to have the data separated for logistics? Can I M/R over a set of keys easily?

Comment: mmm... I am not sure I am following. But considering Cassandra tries to store data to be read sequentially to avoid disk seeks for performance reasons, non-spliting data will give you less disk seeks as columns/rows will be sequentially layed out. Again, I am not sure I am answering your question this time.